# 2D array, some cells hold specific data

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, containers

I have an array of let's say (to make it easier) x and y position. I want to hold **specific data** only for some of the cells and it seems to be complicated. I could hold **specific data** for all cells but I want to hold it only for some of them (no waste of memory, for small 3000x3000 array there is 9 000 000 cells). Also, It has to be really fast. I don't know what to do. Hashing algorithms seem to be for a different kind of problem. I would like to have by e.g. x=50 and y=100 go to the **container** and get **data** quickly but what if x=100 and y=50 etc. Thank you for help.

Comment: Look up "Sparse Matrix"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [unordered set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)

The `key` can be a tuple of x,y

Provide also a class `KeyEqual` that replaces the default one with your custom compare function.

Comment: It seems to be the most accurate way of how I can go through this, thanks

Answer (score 1):

A Matrix is a two dimensional object defined by m row and n columns if most of the element in this Matrix have 0 value is called a **Sparse Matrix**

```
int sparseMatrix[x][y]
```

This is used to reduce computing time by traversing only non-zero elements.

Comment: I've never seen sth like Sparse Matrix, It seems to be really interesting, but I would go for unordered_set, anyway, thank you for sharing solutions

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
int a[sizex][sizey]; //this creates an array with empty slots
a[x][y]=somenumber; //this changes a value of slot on (x,y) coordinates
```

`sizex`: size of x in array

`sizey`: size of y in array

Example:

`e`=empty

```
int a[4][5]; /*creates an array: e, e ,e ,e
                                 e, e ,e ,e
                                 e, e ,e ,e
                                 e, e ,e ,e
                                 e, e ,e ,e*/
a[1][2]=5; /*Now array look like this: e, e ,e ,e
                                       5, e ,e ,e
                                       e, e ,e ,e
                                       e, e ,e ,e
                                       e, e ,e ,e*/
cout<<a[1][2]; //this prints number 5
```

Comment: The problem I described is about something more after you hold some data in an array, some of the cells are unique, like having another data in another container, but this second container is way smaller in size (because there are less unique cells). Then unique cells are bonded with this second container etc.

Answer (score 0):

A HashMap of HashMaps should do just about fine and will serve as a sparse matrix for your use case. It's implementation in different languages would be,

- C++11: `unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, int>> store;`
- Java: `HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>> store = new HashMap<>();`
- Python: `store = defaultdict(dict)`

Comment: Yeah, but I would go for 1D unordered_set, anyway, thanks for help